# Reference old hibernate files from persistence.xml

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have old project that uses Hibernate 3 and I want to upgrade it and use JPA
all mapping was done hbm.xml classes and not JPA annotations.
Can I reference and old hbm.xml files within persistence.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html):

Example of a **persistence.xml** file:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
      <mapping-file>ormap.xml</mapping-file>
      <jar-file>MyApp.jar</jar-file>
      <class>org.acme.Employee</class>
      <class>org.acme.Person</class>
      <class>org.acme.Address</class>
      <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTOVE</shared-cache-mode>
      <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

You are interesting in the `mapping-file` element:

> The class element specifies a EJB3 compliant XML mapping file that you will map. The file has to be in the classpath. As per the EJB3 specification, Hibernate EntityManager will try to load the mapping file located in the jar file at `META_INF/orm.xml`. Of course any explicit mapping file will be loaded too. As a matter of fact, you can provides any XML file in the mapping file element ie. either hbm files or EJB3 deployment descriptor.