# Hibernate/JPA How to load hbm.xml files from external jars using persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA/Hibernate project that needs to use mapping files located in an external jar (a maven dependency). The external jar contains many `hbm.xml` files but I need to load only some of them. The files are not in the root of the jar, they're in subfolders.

I understand that in `hibernate.cfg.xml` you're able to list the `hbm.xml` files you want loaded using the `<mapping>` tag. Is there a way to do something similar in `persistence.xml`?

At the moment I'm physically copying over the `hbm.xml` files from the external jar and placing it in my JPA/Hibernate project's `src/main/resources` folder. This is a temporary solution. I need a way to load the `hbm.xml` directly from the jar.

Comment: But `persistence.xml` is JPA file, can you set location of Hibernate-specific `hbm` files in there? Didn't you mean `xml` files with the JPA entity mapping? Also, how does your path look when it's inside your project?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to figure out: how to set `hbm` files in my `persistence.xml`. At the moment, the `hbm` files are being picked up if I copy them to my `src/main/resources` folder but that's not a solution.

Comment: I understand that. What's weird is that you're _mixing_ JPA (persistence.xml) and Hibernate (hbm.xml). I'm curious if it actually works or you're really doing something different than what you described. I haven't ever used `persistence.xml`, so I don't know for sure that it can't load `hbm.xml`. Just feels wrong..

Comment: Mixing both does work since Hibernate is the JPA implementation I'm using. My only issue is that I can't point Hibernate to `hbm.xml` files in an external jar.

Comment: Could you show us an example of how you specify the path when the files are inside the project?

Comment: I don't need to specify the path as longs as the hbm files are on the root of the jar itself. Hibernate picks them up automatically.

Comment: I see. Have you tried `<jar-file>` or `mapping-file` tags? As mentioned on these pages: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-persistence-xml/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387250/reference-old-hibernate-files-from-persistence-xml

Comment: Mapping file for persistence.xml takes orm.xml format file while I'm working with hb.xml files. Regardless, I found the solution to my problem through a maven plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75197865/859975 I worded the question very generic so it can apply to any scenario

Comment: Well.. that's a workaround, not a solution. If you ever find a better one, don't forget to share it :)